# Scala, cats - convert FUUID with Circe

Tags: scala, uuid, scala-cats, circe

I use this library https://christopherdavenport.github.io/fuuid/ for creating `ID` of custom object and persist them into databse. 
I have a simple `case class` which is my model:

```
import io.chrisdavenport.fuuid.FUUID

case class Bet(
  betId: Option[FUUID],
  home: String,
  away: String,
  stake: BigDecimal,
  betType: String)
```

I used `FUUID` here as an `Option` parameter. I have also a `routes` created with `Http4s` which should take json from input and map it into model:

```
class BettingRoutes[F[_] : Async](service: BettingService[F]) extends Http4sDsl[F] {

  def routes: HttpRoutes[F] = HttpRoutes.of[F] {
    case req@PUT -> Root / "bets" =>
      for {
        bet <- req.as[Bet]
        created <- service.put(bet)
        response <- Created(created)
      } yield response
   }
}
```

I also added some `implicits` to encode and decode from `Circe`:

```
object jsons {
  implicit def circeDecoder[A[_] : Sync, B: Decoder]: EntityDecoder[A, B] = jsonOf[A, B]
  implicit def circeEncoder[A[_] : Sync, B: Encoder]: EntityEncoder[A, B] = jsonEncoderOf[A, B]
}
```

The problem is - when I want to compile project, I got an errors like this in route class:

```
Error:(23, 22) Cannot decode into a value of type model.Bet, because no EntityDecoder[F, model.Bet] instance could be found.
        bet <- req.as[Bet]

Error:(23, 22) not enough arguments for method as: (implicit F: cats.Functor[F], implicit decoder: org.http4s.EntityDecoder[F,model.Bet])F[model.Bet].
Unspecified value parameter decoder.
        bet <- req.as[Bet]

Error:(25, 28) Cannot convert from model.Bet to an Entity, because no EntityEncoder[F, model.Bet] instance could be found.
        response <- Created(created)
```

etc. I investigated it and it appears because of using `FUUID`. I changed all `FUUID` classes to `Long` and after this just to java's `UUID` and then everything compile correctly without errors. The problem is only with `FUUID` and probably with conversion of it. I tried to use `Circe Integration` as It was shown in `FUUID` link above, but it did not help. Do you know how to fix this code to compile everything with `fuuid` and `circe`?
I am new to `cats` and connected libs, so maybe it is a simple mistake, but it is not trivial for me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have `EntityDecoder[F, Bet]` via `jsons.circeDecoder` we firstly need `Decoder[Bet]`. It can be auto-generated by Circe if we have decoders for all fields. The thing is there is `Decoder[UUID]` but no `Decoder[FUUID]`.

So just define necessary implicit

```
implicit val fuuidDecoder: Decoder[FUUID] = Decoder[UUID].map(FUUID.fromUUID)
```

Similarly for encoders

```
implicit val fuuidEncoder: Encoder[FUUID] = Encoder[UUID].contramap(FUUID.Unsafe.toUUID)
```

Comment: Probably `encoder` is necessary too? I have added this one and still has errors connected with Encoder: `Cannot convert from model.Bet to an Entity, because no EntityEncoder[F, model.Bet] instance could be found.
        response <- Created(created)`

Comment: and one more question: why using `Decoder[UUID]`? It is java uuid as I see, but I use `FUUID` or it is other type of `uuid`?

Comment: @allocer "Probably encoder is necessary too?" Yes, I updated the answer.

Comment: @allocer "why using `Decoder[UUID]`?" Because you have this implicit but you need implicit `Decoder[FUUID]`.